# Inconsistent Pytesseract

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I have a directory full of images and want to extract the value from part of it.

I won't bother you with the efforts to extract the exact position of the text from the original image. It's just a convolve function.

**Here's an example of it working:**

Extracted text (this is actually a numpy array of T/F saved as an image with matplotlib imsave(name,image,cmap='gray')):

[image: Extracted Text]

If I now run

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(image2)
```

or

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(image2,config="--psm 7")
```

the result is '3 000 x' as expected.

**Here's an example of it failing:**

Extracted text (this is actually a numpy array of T/F saved as an image with matplotlib imsave(name,image,cmap='gray')):

[image: imageText]

If I now run

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(image2)
```

or

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(image2,config="--psm 7")
```

the result is 'i imol els 4'

> It seems odd to me that there'd be such a big difference for such a similar process. Are there parameters to help pytesseract, eg the expected size of the characters, the format, etc?

PS: My current solution to this problem is to use a convolve function comparing it with a directory of samples that I've already read manually (my personal OCR is better though slower than pytesseract!). This is adequate, but it would be nice to have an additional level of automation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I invert your image and then run this command.

```
tesseract hluZr.png stdout -l eng --oem 3 --psm 6
1508 x
```

Comment: That's a good idea. I guess it might be expecting false on a true background. I'll give that a try. Thanks

Comment: It definitely improves it in the failed cases that I retried. I'm re-doing the whole data set but just inverting seems to work! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that works. Just inverting the image makes it work perfectly.

Comment: Glad it helps. But tesseract itself behave differently on some inputs.

Comment: I just mean that it worked on my data set which is images like this.